# pagination query returns nothing

Tags: sql, t-sql

my query is like this,but it returns nothing
@value0,@value1,@value2,@value3,@field0 changable fields they could be null value or a value depends on the parameters coming from form.
for example when I put these values ,it return nothing
@page = 1,@size = 20,@sort = N'Id',@ts = N'DESC',@field0 = N'Name',@value2 = N'2000-1-1',@value3=null,@value1=null,@value0=null
am I doing something wrong?

```
           @page INT,
            @size INT,@sort nvarchar(50) ,
            @ts nvarchar(50) ,
            @totalrow INT  OUTPUT,
            @value0 nvarchar(50),
            @value1 nvarchar(50),
            @value2 nvarchar(50),
            @value3 nvarchar(50),
            @field0 nvarchar(50)

                AS
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @offset INT
                    DECLARE @newsize INT
                    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)


                    IF(@page=0)
                begin
                SET @offset = @page;
                SET @newsize = @size
                end
                    ELSE 
                begin
                SET @offset = @page+1;
                SET @newsize = @size-1
                end

                    SET NOCOUNT ON;
              SET @sql = '
                     WITH OrderedSet AS
                    (
           SELECT Ks.Id,c.Name,c.CId,Ks.RegisterDate,ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sort + ' '+@ts+') AS ''Index''
           FROM Ks LEFT  OUTER JOIN Car c On c.CId=Ks.CId WHERE  
          AND   (Ks.RegisterDate >'''+@value2+''' OR '''+@value2+''' IS NULL)
          AND (Ks.RegisterDate <'''+@value3+''' OR '''+@value3+''' IS NULL)
         AND (Ks.RegisterDate ='''+@value1+''' OR '''+@value1+''' IS NULL)
          AND ('+@field0+' LIKE ''%'+@value0+'%'' OR @value0 IS NULL)
         )
        SELECT * FROM OrderedSet WHERE [Index] BETWEEN ' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @offset) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), (@offset + @newsize))

                   EXECUTE (@sql)

                   SET @totalrow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Ks])
                   print @sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you concatenate a `null` to a string, the  result is `null`.

I see too many errors in the `SQL syntax` for which I'm guessing the correction. For example if one of the `@value(n) is not null` the other 2 `@value(n)` must be `NULL`

I strongly recommend you to look at the `@sql` value and then correct further errors.

A proposed way to approach the `null` parameters values could be:

```
@page INT,
            @size INT,@sort nvarchar(50) ,
            @ts nvarchar(50) ,
            @totalrow INT  OUTPUT,
            @value0 nvarchar(50),
            @value1 nvarchar(50),
            @value2 nvarchar(50),
            @value3 nvarchar(50),
            @field0 nvarchar(50)

                AS
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @offset INT
                    DECLARE @newsize INT
                    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)


                    IF(@page=0)
                begin
                SET @offset = @page;
                SET @newsize = @size
                end
                    ELSE 
                begin
                SET @offset = @page+1;
                SET @newsize = @size-1
                end

                DECLARE @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition NVARCHAR(1000)

                IF (@value1 IS NULL AND @value2 IS NULL AND @value3 IS NULL)
                BEGIN
                    SET  @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition = N'KsRegisterDate IS NULL'
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    IF (@value1 IS NOT NULL)
                    BEGIN
                        SET  @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition = N'(Ks.RegisterDate ='''+@value1+''''
                    END
                    IF (@value2 IS NOT NULL)
                    BEGIN
                        SET  @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition = N'(Ks.RegisterDate >'''+@value2+''''
                    END
                    IF (@value3 IS NOT NULL)
                    BEGIN
                        SET  @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition = N'(Ks.RegisterDate >'''+@value3+''''
                    END
                END

                IF (NOT (@field0 IS NULL OR @value0 IS NULL ) )
                BEGIN
                    SET  @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition +=  + N'AND ' + @field0+N' LIKE ''%'+@value0+N'%'''
                END 

                    SET NOCOUNT ON;
              SET @sql = '
                     WITH OrderedSet AS
                    (
           SELECT Ks.Id,c.Name,c.CId,Ks.RegisterDate,ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sort + ' '+@ts+') AS ''Index''
           FROM Ks LEFT  OUTER JOIN Car c On c.CId=Ks.CId WHERE  ' + 
          @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition + '
         )
        SELECT * FROM OrderedSet WHERE [Index] BETWEEN ' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), @offset) + ' AND ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), (@offset + @newsize))

                   print @sql
                   EXECUTE (@sql)

                   SET @totalrow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Ks])
```

Comment: but in this case,@value1 and @value2 is not null at the same time ,it get only one condition not both

Comment: so just change the logic to append  `AND` (or `OR`) condition between both and append the conditions, the something like `... DECLARE @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition NVARCHAR(1000) ; set @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition  = ''...` then, the if becomes `SET  @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition = case when @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition  <> '' then N' and ' else '' end + N'(Ks.RegisterDate >'''+@value2+''''`

Comment: I guess u should add + sign too.SET @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition =+

Comment: my bad... it something like: `SET @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition = @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition + case when @Ks_RegisterDate_Condition <> '' then N' and ' else '' end + N'(Ks.RegisterDate >'''+@value2+''''`